# Generics/Delegates and Passing functions with parameters

Tags: c#, .net, function, generics, delegates

I am trying to create a generic CacheManager that I can use all over my application which will ensure that all the management of cache items is done in a consistent manner and adheres to some cache access patterns. This will be used to cache all types of objects as necessary.

I understand I can use a delegate to pass in functions to a method, which you can see below.

```
public static T GetGlobalCacheitem( Func<int ,int , T> populateCacheCall )
        {
            string cacheKey = "test";
            var cachedObject = CacheFactory<T>.GlobalCache.GetGlobalCacheItem(cacheKey);

            if (cachedObject == null)
            {
                cachedObject =  populateCacheCall();
                CacheFactory<T>.GlobalCache.AddGlobalCacheItem(cachedObject, cacheKey);
            }
            return cachedObject;
        }
```

however I have 2 problems.

1. Most of the functions I want to pass in to populate the cache will themselves have paramaters that they need. As in the above instance this is a method which will take two int paramaters. The first question is how can I also pass in the paramaters that I want the function to be invoked with as they will not be know in this cachehandler, that will be known outside of this. ALso this relates to the next question two, and how can I do this in an approach will work work regardless of the number of parameters the function requires (if any)
2. The second problem is that a lot of the functions which I will need to pass in to populate the cache items will be varied , in that some will have no paramaters , some will have one , some may have more than one and the types of each of these paramaters are going to vary. So how would I be able to enable this to work without having to define a function with all possible signatures which will cover every possible combination of functions which pay me used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If parameter of functions will fill outside of GetGlobalCacheitem method, you can defraud calling function with another delegate like this:

```
public static T GetGlobalCacheitem<T>(Func<T> populateCacheCall)
```

and call it:

```
Func<int ,int , object> tempPopulateCacheCall=(a,b)=>new object();

GetGlobalCacheitem(()=>tempPopulateCacheCall(1,2))
```

Or any other function signature with vary parameter

```
Func<int , object> tempPopulateCacheCall=(a)=>new object();

GetGlobalCacheitem(()=>tempPopulateCacheCall(1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pass a `List<P>` parameters as the first param, or use [`Tuple<P>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx) as your param.

Also try to make the global cache key from hash codes of the function and parameters.

If I understood this right, you may find some code as in your scenario in Dapper [`SqlMapper`](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/source/browse/Dapper/SqlMapper.cs) [Identity function](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/source/browse/Dapper/SqlMapper.cs#465)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class, that will encapsulate the function parameters so that you will be able to invoke this function from this class instance without any parameters. The arguments for these parameters will be put in the constructor:

```
interface ICachedFunction<out T>
{
    T Invoke();
}

class CustomFunctionWithVariousParameters<T> : ICachedFunction<T>
{
    private readonly Func<int, string, T> _function;
    private readonly int _parameter1;
    private readonly string _parameter2;

    public CustomFunctionWithVariousParameters(int parameter1, string parameter2, Func<int, string, T> function)
    {
        _function = function;
        _parameter1 = parameter1;
        _parameter2 = parameter2;
    }

    public T Invoke()
    {
        return _function(_parameter1, _parameter2);
    }
}
```

Now you can use this solution in your method:

```
public static T GetGlobalCacheitem( ICachedFunction<T> populateCacheCall )
```

Hope this approach will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I think the structure proposed by Reza Arab is a good as it gets with the structure you have in mind. However, in my opinion, having a global cache is undesirable, especially since it makes effective garbage collection difficult (unless you use weak references to the cached objects. But what about objects that are created and deleted repeatedly? In that case, a weak reference will prohibit efficient caching).